# angular2 include external html template

Tags: angular

Is there a way to include an external html file, I've been unable to use templateUrl, it keeps appending the base to the start of the url.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'enroll-header',
  templateUrl: 'http://blank.blank.com/somecool.html'
})
```

it'll try to find it at `"./http://blank.blank.com/somecool.html"`

and fail

Comment: You might be looking for [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) which includes links to a plnkr and downloadable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an external URL in templateURL is not supported (possibly because it exposes you to security risks). As a workaround you can use a template with your component that binds to and displays a single variable. Then you can set the variable equal to the html you want to render. Please check these two similar SO questions:

- [Dynamically load HTML template in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786490/dynamically-load-html-template-in-angular2)
- [How to load external html page in ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134667/how-to-load-external-html-page-in-ionic2)

Answer (score 2):

I believe all of the templateUrl are relative to the root of your application, so I don't think this would work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a scrape job to get the new html files, and then addded a serverside include command in my index.html file to append them.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Directive({ selector: 'ngInclude' })
export class NgIncludeDirective implements OnInit {

@Input('src')
private templateUrl: string;
@Input('type')
private type: string;

constructor(private element: ElementRef, private http: Http) {

}
parseTemplate(res: Response) {
    if (this.type == 'template') {
        this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = res.text();
    } else if (this.type == 'style') {
        var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res.text()));
        head.appendChild(style);
    }
}
handleTempalteError(err) {

}
ngOnInit() {
    //Loads the HTML and bind it to the view
    this.
        http.
        get(this.templateUrl).
        map(res => this.parseTemplate(res)).
        catch(this.handleTempalteError.bind(this)).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
}

}
```