# AngularJS component with externally hosted templateUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application which I am loading as a plug in into another page with a different path.  Therefore, my template URLs must be fully qualified in order for them to resolve to the correct file.  However, I am receiving `Error: $sce:insecurl
Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked`.

I tried using [resourceUrlWhitelist](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist), but this didn't make my error go away, so I thought I would try [trustAsResourceUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl).  However, I don't know how to combine that with my component's definition.

Here is my component:

```
angular
  .module('synthApp')
  .component('foo', {
    templateUrl: 'http://example.com/app/components/main.template.html',
    controller: MainController
  });

function MainController() {
  ...
}
```

I tried the following but received an error that `$sce` is unknown:

```
angular
  .module('synthApp')
  .component('foo', ['$sce', {
    templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/app/components/main.template.html'),
    controller: MainController
  }]);

function MainController() {
  ...
}
```

What is the proper way to use `trustAsResourceUrl` in this situation?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 include external html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235621/angular2-include-external-html-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`component` accepts a plain object. It cannot be used for DI like `directive`. `.component('foo', ['$sce', { ... }])` isn't a correct syntax for any kind of DI (not just Angular) because it doesn't involve a function where a dependency could be injected.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33846452/3731501), `templateUrl` can be DI-enabled function.

It should be:

```
angular
  .module('synthApp')
  .component('foo', {
    templateUrl: ['$sce', function ($sce) {
      return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://example.com/app/components/main.template.html');
    }],
    controller: MainController
  });
```

Comment: I knew it was bad syntax but I didn't know how to get that `$sce` into the picture.  This worked perfectly.  Thanks!