# AngularJS components to build Chrome Extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angularjs-components

I'm building a Chrome extension and surprisingly, I could create one AngularJS app for the extension side and another for the content script side. The latter is useful to work with a modal-like element injected in the page. I injected this app with this content script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('ContentApp', []);
/**
 * Append the app to the page.
 */
$.get(chrome.runtime.getURL('templates/modal.html'), function(data) {
  $($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body');

  // Manually bootstrapping AngularJS app because template was also manually imported.
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['ContentApp']);
  });
});
```

The problem comes now that `modal.html` is getting big and I still have to add more elements. I thought that I could start creating components in Angular and did it like this:

```
angular.module('ContentApp').
  component('greetUser', {
    template: 'Hello, {{$ctrl.user}}!',
    controller: function GreetUserController() {
      this.user = 'world';
    }
  });
```

This actually works. I can see the `Hello, world` message in the rendered page. But when I changed `template` for `templateUrl`, it failed:

```
// This doesn't work
templateUrl: 'templates/component.html',

// Neither does this
templateUrl: 'templates/component.html',

// Although this is similar to the way I got the main template, it didn't worked either
templateUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('templates/component.html'),
```

Worth to mention that I added the permission to `manifest.json`:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "templates/*"
  ],
```

The error that I got in the console is this:

```
Error: [$sce:insecurl] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$sce/insecurl?p0=chrome-extension%3A%2F%2Fext_id%2Ftemplates%2Fmodal.html
    at chrome-extension://ext_id/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:6:426
    at getTrusted (chrome-extension://ext_id/scripts/lib/angular.min.js:154:156)
```

Does anyone know how to make it work? Or am I asking too much for a Chrome extension?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577208/169252

Comment: Thanks friend, but no luck. I tried adding that configuration in main controller and also in component but didn't work. I also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841974/8796434) but same error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826984/8796434). Thanks to [faboolous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169252/faboolous) who pointed me in the right direction ;)

Since `templateURL` is processed before `$scope` execution, the proper way to secure a template path in a Chrome extension is this:

```
// This works. Yay!
    angular.module('ContentApp').
      component('greetUser', {
        templateUrl: ['$sce', function ($sce) {
          return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(chrome.runtime.getURL('templates/component.html'));
        }],
        controller: function ($scope) {
    ...
```