# How to embed a local HTML page in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to embed a local html files to Ionic pages. 
How can it be possible to embed or import or insert these html tagged local files to Ionic 2 pages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38137455/495157

Comment: thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on stackoverflow and other sites there are lots of different ways to load html files to ionic pages. Simplest way is getting page with `$http.get` method and bind with angular binding to pages.

```
this.http
  .get('something.../test.html')
  .map(response => response.text())
  .subscribe(html => binding_data = html);
```

This method has backdoors for your ionic pages as you know...